# Compiled version of interpolation function slower non-compiled version

Tags: compile

Consider this code:

```
ls = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0., 10., 0.01}];
f = Interpolation[ls];   
g = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate@f[x]]  
(* 
  CompiledFunction[{x},InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][x],-CompiledCode-]
*)

Table[f[x], {x, 0., 10., 0.0001}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.293382, Null}
*)

Table[g[x], {x, 0., 10., 0.0001}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.436141, Null}
*)
```

Why the compiled version slower?

Comment: ... because it is not compiled. You can't compile anything just by wrapping it in `Compile`. See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions) for a list of compilable functions. You can inspect yours by doing ``Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint@g``. You'll see a call to the main evaluator. Because it has to keep going back to the main evaluator for each point, it slows things down further.

Comment: @rm-rf I thought it would print out "proceeding with uncompiled evaluation" if evaluated with uncompiled version. It seems not the case, right?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know exactly under what circumstances that message is produced, but I've always used the CompilePrint function to inspect the result. Maybe someone who knows more about this can comment.

Comment: The message is only printed if a run-time error is encountered and the function has to be re-evaluated at the top level. Since `Compile` knows ahead of time that `InterpolatingFunction` isn't compilable, code is generated for a call out of the VM, and since this is expected, no message is produced.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks for the explanation, but I still don't understand the difference, could you give or refer to some examples?

Comment: Look at the compiled code. Opcodes 46 and 47 represent a call out of the VM. Where these appear, a callback occurs, but no message is printed. Only if a run-time exception occurs during the evaluation of other instructions will the VM abort and evaluate the entire function uncompiled. This is what prompts the message.